# Need help writing a query using SQL EXCEPT

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm writing a query that will show what charities have not donated. Here is my script so far:

```
SELECT c.Name
FROM CHARITY c INNER JOIN
     DONATION d
     ON c.CharityID = d.DonationID
EXCEPT
select C.CharityID, donationID
from charity c join
     DONATION d
     on c.CharityID = d.DonationID
ORDER BY d.DonationID asc
```

My output should state:

```
name                        DonationID
------                       ------
St. Francis Home             NULL
Salvation Army               Null
.....
.....
```

Yet I am getting:

> "Msg 205, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists."

Comment: What part of the message do you not understand?  The error is pretty clear.

Answer (score 1):

How about a `left join` and `where`:

```
SELECT c.Name
FROM CHARITY c LEFT JOIN
     DONATION d
     ON c.CharityID = d.DonationID
WHERE d.DonationID IS NULL;
```

I will point out as well that a join connecting "CharityID" to "DonationID" looks really suspicious.

Comment: There are some charities that have ID I meant to state it in my question 

IE:  "Helping Hands    1000"  and it goes all the way down to